# Whats scrollmagic paneling and how to implement iscroll for anchor navigation?

Tags: jquery, scrollmagic

Thanks Gray Ghost for scrollmagic examples:

`paneling` http://codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/enxAp

`anchor nav`http://codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/EtdwL

does anyone care to explain what is paneling use for in scrollmagic? How is it different from the anchor navigation. And also is there a way to create a non scroll bar base on mouse wheel, maybe using iscroll ?

Answer (score 0):

Anchor navigation just links anchor href hash values to the correlating id on the page. The paneling example is just a way to show full view panels that change/mutate a direction or motion unlike anchor scrolling.